# Conditional if statement in Swift

Tags: swift, conditional-statements

I came across a conditional if statement in Objective-C:

```
self.frontCardView = self.backCardView;
if ((self.backCardView = [self popPersonViewWithFrame:[self backCardViewFrame]])) {
    // Fade the back card into view.
    ...
}
```

Basically:

`if ((self.backCardView = self.popPersonViewWithFrame(self.backCardViewFrame()))) {...}`

This sets "`self.backCardView`" to the return value of
"`-popPersonViewWithFrame:`". In C (and Objective-C), the result of an
assignment is the assigned value.

In this case, the result of the expression "`(self.backCardView = [self
popPersonViewWithFrame:self.backCardViewFrame])`" the return value of
"`-popPersonViewWithFrame:`".

If the return value is "`nil`", then the conditional is not executed (since "`nil`" is a `false` value).

If I try to do the same thing in Swift:

```
self.frontCardView = self.backCardView
if ((self.backCardView = self.popPersonViewWithFrame(self.backCardViewFrame()))) {
    // Fade the back card into view.
    ...
}
```

I get an error in compilation:

> Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'LogicValue'

Comment: just put assignment outside the condition

Comment: Why the double parens around the condition?

Comment: @NRitH: Because they're absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: I don't know anything about Swift but if this was C#-like (in that you need to have a `bool` not an integer or integer-ish value) you'd be trying to do something like `if ((a = b) != nil) { ...` Better yet don't let your `if` statements have side-effects.

Comment: `(self.backCardView = self.popPersonViewWithFrame(self.backCardViewFrame()))` that is not a logic value, you need to use some comparison operator here, like e.g. `(self.backCardView = self.popPersonViewWithFrame(self.backCardViewFrame())) == nil` or something. that will conform the `LogicValue` protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign, then check for nil separately.

```
self.frontCardView = self.backCardView
self.backCardView = self.popPersonViewWithFrame(self.backCardViewFrame())
if self.backCardView != nil {
    // Fade the back card into view.
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift was specifically designed to not allow testing an assignment in a conditional for safety reasons (people accidentally using one `=` instead of two). The result of an assignment operator is always void `()` like the error says.

Answer (score 1):

`()` is simply a typealias for `void`, which is what assignments return in Swift. As Bryan suggested, just put the assignment outside of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

The condition isn't a condition, so like Bryan Chen said, do the assignment outside of the condition, but assign it to another variable. In the condition, then, check whether that variable is equal to `backCardView`, like so:

```
frontCardView = backCardView
let poppedView = self.popPersonViewWithFrame(self.backCardViewFrame())
if backCardView == poppedView {
    // Fade the back card into view.
    ...
```

Comment: See, that's what I tried earlier and it's not actually meeting the same condition that it does in Objective-C.